# Outlook Desktop does not download images from Salesforce

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am having a strange issue where only certain images do not download on Outlook Desktop, specifically from email sent with Salesforce. When I click "Download Images" like I normally would do, instead of seeing the images, I see a small icon with a red x. [This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2638687/pictures-cannot-be-displayed-and-are-shown-as-red-x-in-outlook) describes my issue and I have tried the fix listed (verify that you have the appropriate image cache location in regedit), but it did not resolve my issue. Additionally, most of the time images load properly, only when sent from Salesforce do I have this issue. I can view the image properly on Outlook mobile and Gmail, and if I save the message as HTML and open in Chrome I can see the image, so I know that the image is there and working properly. Are there any Outlook settings I should check in order to fix this?

This is the same question as listed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188318/email-images-not-displaying-only-in-outlook-desktop) in the Salesforce Community, but perhaps this community will be better suited to answering it.

Comment: Are emails from Salesforce somehow in your **Blocked Senders** list? If you add it to **Safe Senders**, do images load correctly?

Comment: @Ashton No, salesforce.com was already in my Safe Senders list. No one is listed in my blocked senders list.

Answer (score 0):

If the common factor is that Salesforce emails are the ones that you receive in **HTML** format, adjusting the following setting will automatically download content for HTML formatted emails:

1. In Microsoft Outlook, click **File**, select **Options**, and click **Trust Center**.
2. Under the **Microsoft Outlook Trust Center** heading, click **Trust Center Settings**.
3. From the **Automatic Download** menu, clear the check box for **Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items**.

[image: Trust Center automatic download settings]